# Extract Nested list from JSON with Retrofit2 Kotlin

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying read a JSON from a url with queries.  I am using Retrofit2 and GSON converter, but I am having trouble solving the following error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

So I understand that it's expecting an array but is receiving an object.  I am using serialized data classes to organize the data I intend to extract, and I am not sure how or where to convert the object into an Array. The guide I followed did it in a single class declaration `class Menu : ArrayList<MenuItem>()`, but I have 5 separate data classes which are nested in a list within the JSON like this:

```
    JSON
    {
      "status": "ok",
      "number": 3,
      "menuItem": [
        {
          "appetizer" : "etc...",
          "options" : {
               "1" : "etc.." 
                }
    
        } ]
        
    }
```

```
data class Menu(
    val menuItems: List<MenuItems>,
    val number: Int,
    val status: String
)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data class MenuItem(

    @SerializedName("appetizer") val appetizer: String,
    @SerializedName("entree") val entree: String,
    @SerializedName("dessert") val dessert: String
)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data class Options(

    @SerializedName("option 1") val option_1: String,
    @SerializedName("option 2") val option_2: String,
    @SerializedName("option 3") val option_3: String
)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data class Flags(
    @SerializedName("dinein") val dinein: Int,
    @SerializedName("takeout") val takeout: Int,
    @SerializedName("delivery") val delivery: Int
)
```

```
Then I also have the API Service interface, the RetrofitInstance, and I tried putting it all together in my Main Activity.  See below:
```

```
interface RetrofitService {

    @GET("/menu/dinner")
    suspend fun getMenu(@Query("restaurant") restaurant:Int, @Query("lat") lat:Double, @Query("long") lon:Double, @Query("maxReturns") maxReturns:Int) : Response<Menu>

}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class RetrofitInstance {

    companion object {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            this.addInterceptor(interceptor)
        }.build()

        val BASE_URL: String = "https://api.my-rest-api-base"
        fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
                .build()
        }
    }

}
```

```
My main activity:
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var retService: tapService
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        // Initialize Retrofit
        retService = tapInstance
            .getTapInstance()
            .create(tapService::class.java)

        // Execute request
        getRequestWithQueryParameters()
    }

    // get request
    private fun getRequestWithQueryParameters() {

        // set query parameters
        val restaurant = "McDonalds"
        val latt = 40.7539
        val lon = -74.40816
        val maxreturns = 3
        
        val responseLiveData: LiveData<Response<Restaurant>> = liveData {
            val response= retService.getMenu(restaurant, latt, lon, maxreturns)
            emit(response)
        }
        responseLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            val menuList = it.body()?.listIterator()  // here it's supposed to iterate through 
                      //arraylist, but i don't know how to access the sub-list MenuItems
            if(menuList!=null) {
                while (menuList.hasNext()) {
                    val menuItem = menuList.next()
                    val result =
                            " " + "Appetizer : ${menuItem.appetizer}" + "\n" +
                            " " + "Entree : ${menuItem.entree}" + "\n" +
                            " " + "Dessert : ${menuItem.dessert}" + "\n\n\n"
                    text_view1.append(result)
                }
            }
        }
        )
    }
```

I don't know how to access these sub-lists and sub-dictionaries within my JSON.  I was able to get the JSON downloaded but then it crashes with the fatal exception listed in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Something's wrong here,

```
@GET("/menu/dinner")
    suspend fun getMenu(@Query("restaurant") restaurant:Int, @Query("lat") lat:Double, @Query("long") lon:Double, @Query("maxReturns") maxReturns:Int) : Response<Menu>
```

Since it is a suspend function, it should probably not return `Response<T>`, you should probably just return `Menu`

```
@GET("/menu/dinner")
    suspend fun getMenu(@Query("restaurant") restaurant:Int, @Query("lat") lat:Double, @Query("long") lon:Double, @Query("maxReturns") maxReturns:Int) : Menu
```

Also make changes to your `responseLiveData`

```
val responseLiveData: LiveData<Menu> = liveData {
            val response= retService.getMenu(restaurant, latt, lon, maxreturns)
            emit(response)
        }
```

And in your observer, you can directly use your Menu object

```
responseLiveData.observe(this, Observer { menu ->
            val menuList = menu.menuItems
            //this is your data class, you can use it directly
        }
```

Comment: Making the suggested change causes an error with the `emit(response)` function found in the main activtiy as the emit function is expecting a Response<T> object

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to return the appropriate data from the `liveData { }`